# How to map a json list only after an onclick event in react?

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

Is there a way to use map() in order to feel objects into a datalist element, only after user clicks on that input?

for instance, I want the list of languages below to start filling data only if the user clicks on its input:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import languages from './languages.json';
    const langLi = languages.languages.map(languages => // i want this to happen only after clicking the input
        <option>
                {languages.lang}
        </option>
        )
class Form extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <form>
                <input type='text' list='langData'/>
                    <datalist id='langData'>{langLi}</datalist> //
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

When I inserted an onClick trigger to the input and wrote a function that fills the datalist's innerHTML, nothing happened. Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks!

Example of languages.json:

```js
{
    "languages":[
            {"lang": "Chinese",
            "country": "China",
            "rank": 1},
            {"lang": "Spanish",
            "country": "Spain",
            "rank": 2},
            {"lang": "English",
            "country": "United Kingdom",
            "rank": 3}
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage state on your React Component and insert elements via call function when event of your input is calling.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import languages from './languages.json';

class Form extends Component {
    construct(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            languages: []
        }
    }

    addLanguagesHandler = () => {
        const myLanguages = this.state.languages;
        myLanguages.push(); // <= Push your languages here
        
        // Map new languages to state
        this.setState({
            languages: myLanguages
        })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <form>
                <input type='text' list='langData' onFocus={() => this.addLanguagesHandler()} />
                    <datalist id='langData'>
                        {this.state.languages.map((language, index) => (
                            {/* Your logic for UI */}
                            <option key={index}>{language}</option>
                        ))}
                    </datalist>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you have, and more than one

But one important thing to note: you are inside react, therefore you need to use react and not manipulate Dom directly.

You can fill state. I. e.  this. setState({languages: fill()}) inside onclick
You can use a reducer
You can run this. languages = fillMyList(); and then this.forceUpdate(). this will fill the list with languages and then will rerender react shadow Dom (which in turn will update the real dom